# How to display a payment block for a specific product WooCommerce PayPal Payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I have a Wordpress WooCommerce site. Worth recommended WooCommerce plugin for PayPal payment. I have hooks `'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form'`, `'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button'`, `'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button'`, `'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form'` in my theme in each product. In other themes, PayPal buttons seem to be displayed with these hooks. Do I need to write something in function.php or use other hooks